# Multi save list in Spring MVC?

Tags: list, spring-mvc

Is there any way to save list of object and their collections just by one click save?
I mean list populated with already filled input text by object's value and justONE button "Save" to update all the items of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Create one long JSON String and send it to your SPring MVC Controller.

See these posts for help:

[JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908466/225396)

[Problem with Spring 3 + JSON : HTTP status 406?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4982966/225396)