# jquery ajax response append to sclect tag (state-district wise)

Tags: spring, scala, jquery

In this scenario based on two combo box state and district

**my javascript**

```
   <script>


    function selectState() {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : '/learnware/selectstate.html',
            data : ({ 
                 id : $('#state').val() 
                 }),
            success: function(responseData) {
            if(responseData != null) {
                $('#district')
                .find('option')
                .remove()
                .end();

                 $.each(responseData, function(index,item) {    
                     $('#district').append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(item['id']).html(item['name'])
                            );                     
                    });  
            }  
        }

         });    
    }


</script>
```

Here my controller is on scala integrated with spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("selectstate.html"))
  @ResponseBody
  def getState(@RequestParam id: Long): java.util.List[District] = {
  var districtList:List[District]=null
    if(id!=null){
     var districtList:List[District]=districtService.findDistrictListByStateId(id) 
     println(districtList)
    }
    districtList
  }
```

**And finally my html combobox**

```
<select id="state" onchange="selectState();">

<option th:each="s : ${states}" th:text="${s.stateName}" th:value="${s.id}">India</option>

</select>


<select id="district" >

<option ></option>

</select>
```

The problem is when i change the select box value the browser(chrome) console gives me some error and it does not change to district select box

**Error on browser console**

```
POST http://localhost:8080/learnware/selectstate.html 406 (Not Acceptable) jquery.js:8706
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread with a 406 HTTP Status response

[Spring JSON request getting 406 (not Acceptable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)

In general it means that the content type your browser(chrome) is requesting cannot be delivered by the server. The chrome browser indicates its desired content type in the Http Accept header.

So there are several things you could check:

1. Check in chrome's developer if the http Accept header is different in the request and fix that accordingly.
2. If not, it is probably the response which cannot be generated. The link suggests that the Jackson JSON Mapper could not be registered or that the library is not on your classpath.