# Spring Controller integration test fails to parse response and fails the test with 406 HTTP code

Tags: java, spring, controller, jackson, integration-testing

i am trying to do integration tests for my controllers, but for some reason the test context fails to parse back the response and causes the test to fail, and throwing 406 HTTP code.

I have jackson mapper bean in context.

Here is the code:

Controller:

> ```
> @Controller
> @RequestMapping({"/user"})
> public class UserController 
> {
>     Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
>     @RequestMapping(value = "isloggedin",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
>     @ResponseBody
>     public ServerResponse<Boolean> isloggedin() {
>     return new ServerResponse<Boolean>(true, HttpStatus.OK, "logged in");
> }
> ```

Test context:

> ```
> @PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")})
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"X.Y.Z.controllers", "X.Y.Z.webresources"})
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebMvcConfig.class})
> public class ControllerIntegrationUnitTestContext extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {}
> ```

inside WebMvcConfig i have:

> ```
> @Bean
> @Autowired
> public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter d){
>     RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
>     List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new LinkedList<>();
>     messageConverters.add(d);
>     requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
>     return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
> }
> ```

Test class:

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerIntegrationUnitTestContext.class})
> @WebAppConfiguration
> public class SampleUnitTest {
> private MockMvc mockMvc;
> @Autowired
> private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;
> @Before
> public void setUp() {
>     mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
> }
> @Test
> public void testrun() throws Exception{
>     mockMvc.perform(get("/user/isloggedin").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("true"));
> }}
> ```

and the error i am getting when running the test:

> ```
>   2014-06-04 20:54:15,911 [DEBUG] [FrameworkServlet,initWebApplicationContext(),558] - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet '' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.]
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,911 [INFO] [FrameworkServlet,initServletBean(),498] - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 151 ms
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,911 [DEBUG] [HttpServletBean,init(),139] - Servlet '' configured successfully
>   2014-06-04 20:54:15,933 [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet,doService(),838] - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing GET request for [/user/isloggedin]
>   2014-06-04 20:54:15,937 [DEBUG] [AbstractUrlHandlerMapping,getHandlerInternal(),124] - Mapping [/user/isloggedin] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [X.Y.Z.controllers.UserController@17da0d1] and 1 interceptor
>   2014-06-04 20:54:15,939 [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet,doDispatch(),925] - Last-Modified value for [/user/isloggedin] is: -1
>   2014-06-04 20:54:15,945 [DEBUG] [HandlerMethodInvoker,invokeHandlerMethod(),172] - Invoking request handler method: public X.Y.Z.webresources.ServerResponse X.Y.Z.controllers.UserController.isloggedin()
>    2014-06-04 20:54:15,949 [DEBUG] [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver,resolveException(),134] - Resolving exception from handler [X.Y.Z.controllers.UserController@17da0d1]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
>    2014-06-04 20:54:15,950 [DEBUG] [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver,resolveException(),134] - Resolving exception from handler [X.Y.Z.controllers.UserController@17da0d1]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,950 [DEBUG] [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver,resolveException(),134] - Resolving exception from handler [X.Y.Z.UserController@17da0d1]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,950 [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet,processDispatchResult(),1012] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,950 [DEBUG] [FrameworkServlet,processRequest(),991] - Successfully completed request
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,953 [DEBUG] [DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,afterTestMethod(),94] - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@12cf9bd testClass = SampleUnitTest, testInstance = context.SampleUnitTest@1c012fa, testMethod = testrun@SampleUnitTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@14c92a7 testClass = SampleUnitTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class context.ControllerIntegrationUnitTestContext}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
>    2014-06-04 20:54:15,954 [DEBUG] [ServletTestExecutionListener,afterTestMethod(),138] - Resetting RequestContextHolder for test context [DefaultTestContext@12cf9bd testClass = SampleUnitTest, testInstance = context.SampleUnitTest@1c012fa, testMethod = testrun@SampleUnitTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@14c92a7 testClass = SampleUnitTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class context.ControllerIntegrationUnitTestContext}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,957 [DEBUG] [DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,afterTestClass(),126] - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@12cf9bd testClass = SampleUnitTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@14c92a7 testClass = SampleUnitTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class context.ControllerIntegrationUnitTestContext}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
>     2014-06-04 20:54:15,958 [INFO] [AbstractApplicationContext,doClose(),873] - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@9b46a8: startup date [Wed Jun 04 20:54:15 IDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
>      2014-06-04 20:54:15,958 [DEBUG] [AbstractBeanFactory,doGetBean(),249] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
> ```

I am kind of stuck with this and dont know what more to do to make this work

**Progress:**

the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` was not in context, now it is. but i am getting a

> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>    ...     
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
> ```

**Progress**

updated jackson version, now everything works fine.

Comment: See if any of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202) help. It covers most if not all of the causes of a 406 using Jackson.

Comment: A quick debug step is to remove the `produces` from your request mapping, and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler is mapped with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "isloggedin",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

It *produces* `application/json`. For this to work, your client must `Accept` `application/json`. Currently your `MockMvc` request does not specify such an `Accept` header. Add one.

Comment: exactly the same:  java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406

Comment: @Gleeb Put a log message in your handler method. Does it get printed? Instead of creating a custom `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, try using the default one but configuring your message converters with the `configureCustomMessageConverters` method (or whatever it's called) of the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class.

Comment: OK apparently the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter bean was not in the context. but now that it is. i am getting the following. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException and i have all the dependencies for jackson.

Comment: @Gleeb `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` requires Jackson 2. Do you have Jackson 1 or 2? Double check those dependencies.