# ajax POST 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I have next ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success" + response);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        var errorMessage = $(jqXHR.responseText).filter('p:eq(1)').find('u').text();
        alert("error " + errorMessage);
    }
});
```

where I transmit the letter entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LETTERS")
public class Letter {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "CREATING_DATE")
    private Date creatingDate;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_DATE")
    private Date deliveringDate;

    public Letter() {
    }
    //... getters and setters
}
```

and in my controller I can't get this entity cause unsupported media type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addLetterToDB(@RequestBody Letter letter) {
    System.out.println(letter);
}
```

But if I change in method signature Letter type to String type it will works, but I wanna take the entity) Pls help.

Comment: Found answer just add dependecies for new spring version 4.1.7
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Produces` annotation and put there application/json. You also need a mechanism to convert the result (Letter) to JSON. Use Jackson or Gson.