# How to set content-type for a spring boot test case which returns PDF file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, testcase, spring-boot-test

I am currently testing one of my services with Spring boot test.The service exports all user data and produces a CSV or PDF after successful completion. A file is downloade in browser.

Below is the code i have wrote in my test class

```
MvcResult result =   MockMvc.perform(post("/api/user-accounts/export").param("query","id=='123'")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(userObjectDTO)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
    .andReturn();
String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();  // verify the response string.
```

Below is my resource class code (call comes to this place)-

```
    @PostMapping("/user-accounts/export")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportAllUsers(@RequestParam Optional<String> query, @ApiParam Pageable pageable, 
@RequestBody UserObjectDTO userObjectDTO) {
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
.
.
.

 return new ResponseEntity<>(outputContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

 }
```

While I debug my service, and place debug just before the exit, I get content Type as 'application/pdf' and status as 200.I have tried to replicate the same content type in my test case. Somehow it always throws below error during execution -

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
   Expected :200
   Actual   :406
```

I would like to know, how should i inspect my response (ResponseEntity). Also what should be the desired content-type for response.

Comment: As I told you in chat: an hour is a short time on Stack Overflow. If you want a response sooner, hire a developer. I edited your [previous, exact duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54125546/5211833) to at least have a proper question statement. The way to go on Stack Overflow is then to wait whilst your question passes through the review queue, not by abusing the system and simply deleting and reasking it. Please do take into consideration that everyone here is a volunteer, and all are equal. You are not entitled or such to a response within minutes, it's up to the answerers.

Comment: yes, you have updated the previous question, and I got desperate to get an answer.I am aware an hour is not long time to spare. But sometime we do get desperate to finish our work. So it caused this mess.

Comment: Which, as I told you three times by now, is of no concern to us. You ask a question, and people may or may not volunteer their time to help you. Abusing the system by spamming your question as often as you can in vain hope to get an answer is not tolerated. You'll have to simply sit and wait for an answer. Better questions get answers sooner, so try to improve your question in all aspects (language, code, examples, errors etc), and if you still do not receive an answer after two days, you can put a bounty on it. If that fails, that's the way it is then.

Comment: okay. i got your point.

Comment: Complete guess @NarendraPandey try `contentTypeCompatibleWith` instead of `contentType`

Comment: @Darren I got following response after changing `contentType` to `contentTypeCompatibleWith` - Content type [application/problem+json] is not compatible with [application/pdf]

Comment: Would it possible for you to provide a working example producing the error ? Something as a GitHub project will be ideal. It appears issue with the way your project is set up. Share all the spring configuration that you have.

Comment: @Veeram, will try to provide one. thanks

Comment: What is your spring-webmvc dependency and spring-boot jar version ?

Comment: hello @Veeram , spring mvc version is 5.0.5 and spring boot jar version is 2.0.1

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876635/spring-rest-returning-pdf-response-status-406-not-acceptable

Comment: @JacobSTL , yes it looks identical to it. i am already implementing the given solution. it seems my testcase lacks something.

Comment: I don’t believe your test case is lacking anything and I think it is exception or error somewhere in spring or other library that we can’t see. Try debugging spring source code where the application/problem json media type is produced. It will be worthwhile to set up a GitHub project. Do you use any problem detail module like https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web that usually produce the problem json media type ?

Comment: @Veeram hello Veeram, as suggested i debugged the spring code. and got to know that `Mapping2JacksonHttpMessageConverter` was having default support values i.e. `application/json` & `application*\json`. I override these properties and it resolve the issue.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer with help of @veeram and came to understand that my configuration for `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` were lacking as per my requirement. I override its default supported `Mediatype` and it resolved the issue.

Default Supported -

```
implication/json
application*/json
```

Code change done to fix this case -

```
@Autowired
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.ALL);
jacksonMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
```

Answer (score 8):

You have problem some where else. It appears that an exception/error occurred as noted by  application/problem+json content type. This is probably set in the exception handler. As your client is only expecting application/pdf 406 is returned.

You can add a test case to read the error details to know what exactly the error is.

Something like

```
MvcResult result = MockMvc.perform(post("/api/user-accounts/export").param("query","id=='123'")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_VALUE)
    .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(userObjectDTO)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_VALUE))
    .andReturn();
String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();  // This should show you what the error is and you can adjust your code accordingly.
```

Going forward if you are expecting the error you can change the accept type to include both pdf and problem json type.

Note - This behaviors is dependent on the spring web mvc version you have.

The latest spring mvc version takes into account the content type header set in the response entity and ignores what is provided in the accept header and parses the response to format possible. So the same test you have will not return 406 code instead would return the content with application json problem content type.

Comment: As you mentioned in your note, that return will depend on your spring web mvc, could you point to a doc reference.HOw could we actually test in such case. I would like to compare the end result content type as "application/pdf"

Comment: HI @veeram, I followed the above approach and did found the 406 error with more detailed body, i.e.`{ "type" : "http://abc-aaa/problem/problem-with-message", "title" : "Not Acceptable", "status" : 406, "detail" : "Could not find acceptable representation", "path" : "/api/user-accounts/export", "message" : "error.http.406" }`

Comment: Look at the github [comments](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20720) .The end result content type is not application/pdf. That is the problem. How are you setting the content type ? . Is it part of response entity header ? As per 5.0.5 you shouldn't be getting 406 error if you setting the content type in the header and has no produce annotation.

Comment: the header is set manually in our service the following way `headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("fileName", filename);
            headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");` and later returned the following way `return new ResponseEntity<>(outputContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`.usually we get download file in our browser. But in test case execution, it gets converted from HTTP.200 to 406 and application/pdf to application/problem+json

Comment: hello Veeram, as suggested i debugged the spring code. and got to know that `Mapping2JacksonHttpMessageConverter` was having default support values i.e. `application/json` & `application*\json`. I override these properties and it resolve the issue.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

406 means your client is asking for a contentType (probably pdf) that the server doesn't think it can provide.

I'm guessing the reason your code is working when you debug is that your rest client is not adding the ACCEPT header that asks for a pdf like the test code is.

To fix the issue, add to your @PostMapping annotation `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE` see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html#produces--

Comment: Hello JacobSTL, I made the the necessary changes but yet i recived following error `java.lang.AssertionError: Content type 
Expected :application/pdf
Actual   :application/problem+json` . I believe we have not used any specific produce type as we use this service to download both PDF ans CSV type files.

Comment: If you want to send different content types based on the ACCEPT header received, then you need seperate controller methods, split by header, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html#headers--

Comment: I tried with following resource's method definition, ` @PostMapping(value="/user-accounts/export",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,"text/csv"})` but still got http error code 406. I would like to verify the response type as 'application/pdf' but it comes to `application/problem+json`