# "Could not find acceptable representation" when testing spring download link with MockMvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that should allow downloading files with arbitrary content type:

```
@GetMapping(value="/download/{directory}/{name}",
            consumes=MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@PathVariable String directory,
                                           @PathVariable String name) {
    log.debug("REST request to download File : {}/{}", directory, name);

    byte[] content = "it works".getBytes();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I want to test that in a unit test like this:

```
...
private MockMvc restFileMockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    final FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(fileService);
    this.restFileMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(fileResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
        .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
        .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
        .setValidator(validator).build();
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void downloadFile() throws Exception {
    String url = "/api/download/it/works.txt";
    restFileMockMvc.perform(get(url).header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*/*"))
                   .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()) // Debugging only!
                   .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

But obviously, there is a problem with the content type, resp. the accept header.  `MockMvcResultHandlers.print()` produces the following:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/download/DIRDIR/NAMENAME
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[*/*]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.storage.web.rest.FileResource
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<byte[]> com.example.storage.web.rest.FileResource.downloadFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 406
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/problem+json]}
     Content type = application/problem+json
             Body = {"type":"https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message","title":"Not Acceptable","status":406,"detail":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/api/download/DIRDIR/NAMENAME","message":"error.http.406"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

It looks like the request is sent with `Accept: */*`.  What does Spring complain about then?

Comment: You don't have a `Content-Type` header only an `Accept` header.

Comment: @M. Deinum `Content-Type` is a response header and `Accept` is a request header.

Comment: `Content-Type` is both request and response.

Comment: But this is a get request. It has no body.

Comment: It still expects the header. Remove the `consumes` part from your `@RequstMapping`.

Comment: Can you post code for `restFileMockMvc`. What message converter are you using

Comment: @M. Deinum, yes the `consumes` was nonsense in this context. It should rather be `produces` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: @Narendra Pandey I have added the code how `restFileMockMvc` is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be an issue with your message converter, used in your test case. I too faced similar issue and resolved it by passing additional parameter in  messageConverter for my mockMvc

```
 this.restMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
        .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter,new 
       ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()).build();
```

You need to overload message converter property for MockMVC. for more info , [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128369/how-to-set-content-type-for-a-spring-boot-test-case-which-returns-pdf-file)

Comment: Adding the `new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()` did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your answer helped me!
If you return ResponseEntity<Resource>, you need to add ResourceHttpMessageConverter into messageConverters.

Answer (score 0):

I was already using `@SpringJUnitWebConfig(...)` and included the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to my imported Config. This seemed to add all the necessary converters. E.g.

```java
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(MyTestConfig.class)
class MyTest {

  @Inject
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  ...
}

@EnableWebMvc
class MyTestConfig {
  @Bean
  ...
}
```