# Spring + AngularJS - the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial on building an e-commerce web application with spring framework in Intellij Idea, and i have a problem with the the shopping cart functionality.

The functionality  works fine : I can add product to it but when i want to show the product in the cart nothing is shown

This is my code

The CartController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private CartDao cartDao;

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}",headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        return cartDao.read(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}",headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId, @RequestBody Cart cart) {
        cartDao.update(cartId, cart);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}",headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        cartDao.delete(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productId}",headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable (value = "productId") String productId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String sessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart = cartDao.read(sessionId);

        if(cart == null) {
            cart = cartDao.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }

        Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
        if(product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new Exception());
        }

        cart.addCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartDao.update(sessionId, cart);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productId}",headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeItem(@PathVariable(value = "productId") String productId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String sessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart = cartDao.read(sessionId);

        if(cart == null) {
            cart = cartDao.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }

        Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
        if(product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new Exception());
        }

        cart.removeCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartDao.update(sessionId, cart);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Illigal request, please verify your payload")
    public void handleClientError(Exception e) {}


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Internal Server Error")
    public void handleServerError(Exception e) {}

}
```

The CartDao

```
public interface CartDao {

    Cart create(Cart cart);

    Cart read(String cartId);

    void update (String cartId, Cart cart);

    void delete (String cartId);
}
```

The Implementation of the CartDao

```
@Repository
public class CartDaoImpl implements CartDao{

    private Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts;

    public CartDaoImpl() {
        listOfCarts = new HashMap<String, Cart>();
    }

    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        if(listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cart.getCartId())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot create a cart. A cart with the given id(%) " + "already" + "exists", cart.getCartId()));
        }

        listOfCarts.put(cart.getCartId(), cart);

        return cart;
    }

    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return listOfCarts.get(cartId);
    }

    public void update(String cartId, Cart cart) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot create cart. The cart with the given id(%) " + "does not" + "exist", cart.getCartId()));
        }

        listOfCarts.put(cartId, cart);
    }

    public void delete(String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot delete cart. A cart with the given id(%) " + "does not" + "exists", cartId));
        }

        listOfCarts.remove(cartId);
    }
}
```

The model ( Cart.java)

```
public class Cart {
    private String cartId;
    private Map<String, CartItem> cartItems;
    private double grandTotal;

    private Cart() {
        cartItems = new HashMap<String, CartItem>();
        grandTotal = 0 ;
    }

    public Cart(String cartId) {
        this();
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public String getCartId() {
        return cartId;
    }

    public void setCartId(String cartId) {
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public Map<String, CartItem> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(Map<String, CartItem> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public double getGrandTotal() {
        return grandTotal;
    }

    public void setGrandTotal(double grandTotal) {
        this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
    }

    public void addCartItem (CartItem item) {
        String productId = item.getProduct().getProductId();

        if(cartItems.containsKey(productId)) {
            CartItem existingCartItem = cartItems.get(productId);
            existingCartItem.setQuantity(existingCartItem.getQuantity()+item.getQuantity());
            cartItems.put(productId, existingCartItem);
        } else {
            cartItems.put(productId, item);
        }

        updateGrandTotal();
    }

    public void removeCartItem (CartItem item) {
        String productId = item.getProduct().getProductId();
        cartItems.remove(productId);
        updateGrandTotal();
    }

    public void updateGrandTotal() {
        grandTotal = 0;
        for (CartItem item : cartItems.values()) {
            grandTotal = grandTotal + item.getTotalPrice();
        }
    }
}
```

The controller.js file that contains all the functions for the Cart functionality

```
var cartApp = angular.module("cartApp", []);

cartApp.controller("cartCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.refreshCart = function (cartId) {
        $http.get('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.cart=data;
        });
    };

    $scope.clearCart = function () {
        $http.delete('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));
    };

    $scope.initCartId = function (cartId) {
        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function (productId) {
          $http.put('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/add/'+productId).success(function (data) {
              $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/cartId'));
              alert("Le produit a été ajouté au panier")
          });
    };

    $scope.removeFromCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/eCafeteriaStore/rest/cart/cartId'));
        });
    };

});
```

the JSP file viewProduct where i can see the "Add to cart button" and the "view cart" button

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Products Information</h1>

            <p class="lead">View product details</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${product.productId}.png"/> " alt="image" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <h3>${product.productName}</h3>
                    <p>${product.productDescription}</p>
                    <p><strong>Manufacturer</strong> : ${product.productManufacturer}</p>
                    <p><strong>Categorie</strong> : ${product.productCategory}</p>
                    <p><strong>Condition</strong> : ${product.productCondition}</p>
                    <p>${product.productPrice} DH</p>

                    <br>

                    <c:set var="role" scope="page" value="${param.role}" />
                    <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/productList" />
                    <c:if test="${role='admin'}" >
                        <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/admin/productInventory" />
                    </c:if>

                    <p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
                        <a href="<c:url value="${url}" /> " class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large"
                           ng-click="addToCart('${product.productId}')"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add to Cart</a>
                        <a href="<spring:url value="/cart" />"
                           class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>View Cart</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js" /> "></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

And this is the cart.jsp. this is where the products added to the cart supposed to be and i see nothing

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>

                    <p>The products in your Cart</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div ng-controller = "cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="clearCart()"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Clear</a>
            </div>


            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat = "item in cart.cartItems">
                    <td>{{item.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.productId)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Supprimer</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>{{cart.grandTotal}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <a href="<spring:url value="/productList" />" class="btn btn-default">Continuer Shooping</a>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js" /> "></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

I have included Angular in the header section

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js" > </script>
```

When i tried to debug the cart.jsp page i have this message in the developers tool in Chrome  `" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) "`

And this Apache error 406

```
 The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

Can anyone help me with this please

Comment: It is likely that you dont have json converter on the classpath. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)

Comment: @AlecKravets I had to add the jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar as the topic in the link said

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: try to add UTF-8 encoding to your server.xml in tomcat