# get object from controller in ajax - spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to get object from controller in ajax method, but I always get error.
This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUpdatableCard",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Card getUpdatableCard(@RequestParam("card") long id) {
    Card card = null;
    for(int i = 0;i<cards.size();i++) {
        if(cards.get(i).getId()==id) {
            card = cards.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(card.getExpression());
    System.out.println(card.getCardType().getName());
    System.out.println(id);

    return card;
}
```

This is my ajax function:

```
function addAttribute() {
var card = $('#card').val();
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: contexPath + "/getUpdatableCard",
    data:"card=" + card,
    success:function(data) {
        $("#cardUpdate").modal("show");
        alert(data.id);
    },
    error:function(e) {
        alert('QIRAGI')
    }
});
```

}

in the web console:
status:406
statusText:not acceptable

please help me.

Comment: You should include details on the error that you are getting.

Comment: i get only alert message.

Comment: what does the alert message say?

Comment: 'QIRAGI' as written in error function.

Comment: i edited my question.i added error from web console.

Comment: will you please update your question with the error message and from where that "cards" variable comes in your loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
>   response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the accept headers sent in the request.

This situation can occur due to many reasons,Either you don't have the correct Jackson library in your classpath, or you haven't used the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` directive.

Maybe you are missing some of **JAR** files also.

[Spring JSON request getting 406 (not Acceptable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)

Comment: Yes i solved this problem.I missed some of jackson libs.

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUpdatableCard/{card}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Card getUpdatableCard(@PathVariable long card) {


    return card;  // break point. you confirm "card". 
}
```

js

```
function addAttribute() {
    var card = $('#card').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: contexPath + "/getUpdatableCard/" + card,

        success:function(data) {
            $("#cardUpdate").modal("show");
            alert(data.id);
        },
        error:function(e) {
            alert('QIRAGI')
        }
    });
}
```