# 406 Not acceptable with Accept header any

Tags: spring, rest, http-status-code-406

I am trying to do DELETE http request to an API ( I don't have access to the source code of it) but the API keeps responding with 406.

I tried to put "Accept" header any but the issue still the same, I see the headers are correct.
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you post the spring version you are using and also the jackson jar version if used?

Comment: @harshavmb spring boot 1.3.7.RELEASE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable help you