# How do I get the values of the model returned from Controller in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

AdminController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="show_allMember.do",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String memberList(ModelAndView mav)
    {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> members = aService.getMemberList();
        mav.addObject("mList",members);

        System.out.println("model is that : " + mav);

        return "" + mav ;
    }
```

adminMainPage.jsp

```
function show_allMember()
{
    $('.member_management_area').css('display','block');
    $('.member_management').css('color','#fe4978');

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rachelivf/show_allMember.do',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(mList)
        {
            console.log(mList);
            $.each(response.mList, function(index, value)
            {
                console.log(response.list);
            });
       },
       error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError)
       {
           if(xhr.status == 404)
         {
               alert(thrownError);
         }
       }
     });
}
```

I tried to find the way. But it failed.

I want to get the values ​​of the model returned from the controller in 
ajax and display it in jsp.

But I don't know how.

As a beginner, I do not know much, so I ask a lot of questions. 
Please let me know if I have provided the information properly. 
Please let me know if the gist of the question is wrong. 
I need your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `return type` to  `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` instead of `String` and return **`members`**,

```
@RequestMapping(value="show_allMember.do",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String memberList(ModelAndView mav)
{
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> members = aService.getMemberList();
    return members ;
    //OR
    //return aService.getMemberList();

}
```

In Ajax Success try to access as

```
type: 'GET',
success: function(mList)
    {
        console.log(mList);
        $.each(response.mList, function(index, value)
        {
            console.log(value.yourMapKey);
        });
   },
```

Changed `method = RequestMethod.POST` to `method = RequestMethod.GET`
Hope this help...

Comment: An error has occurred 406() error in developer toos TT

Comment: changed value to `value="/show_allMember.do"` add `/`

Comment: Have you added `Jackson` library jars ?

Comment: Have lokk at this for 406 Not Acceptable https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469297/3425489

Comment: I will refer to it.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkk OMG.. I modified the ajax code to type = 'GET', but the controller did not make any modifications. So I got an error .. I am a fool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151336/discussion-between-shantaram-t-and-).

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need using `GET` for getting data from server.
2. You don't need using `ModelAndView`. It is using for create html page by `ViewResolver` - it takes the form of a String view name and put into the form objects from a model.

You can just return needed data from method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="show_allMember.do",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<HashMap<String, Object>> memberList()
    {
        return aService.getMemberList();
    }
```

And fix request:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/rachelivf/show_allMember.do',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success: function(response)
    {
        $.each(response, function(index, value)
        {
            console.log(value);
        });
   },
   error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError)
   {
       if(xhr.status == 404)
     {
           alert(thrownError);
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: success: In the function (response) part, does the response contain the value returned by the controller?

Comment: response is the value returned by the controller (`responce has type List<HashMap<String, Object>>`)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I do not know how to talk 1: 1. I would appreciate it if you walk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151338/discussion-between-nikolay-and-).