# HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on simple Spring-MVC application(Not Maven) where I want to make a web service which returns a boolean but it gives a HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable error.
Also I am trying to call a it from a JSP.

**JSP :**

```html
 <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getformatretension" method="post" id="form">
  <p>
   loc 1: <input type="text" name="srcUrl" size="45" id="file" />
  </p>
   <p>  
            loc 2 : <input type="text" name="xlfUrl" size="45" id="xlffile"/>  
       </p><input type="Submit" value = "Submit">      
 </form>
```

**Controller :**

```
public class MyClassController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getformatretension", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> methodName(@RequestParam("srcUrl") String srcUrl
            ,@RequestParam("xlfUrl") String xlfUrl) throws IOException{

        int nReturnVal = JsoupParserHtml.test(xlfUrl, srcUrl); 
        String mimeType=  "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", mimeType);
           if(nReturnVal ==  1) 
           { 
                System.out.println("Success");
                return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(true,HttpStatus.OK);

           }
           else {
               System.out.println("error");
               return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(false,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
           }

        }
```

Error :

> HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Description The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

Comment: have you added Jackson libraries jars ?

Comment: Yes, I have added jackson-all-1.9.0.jar in libraries

Comment: please follow this Question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7462202/3425489

Comment: No luck, I believe that the above link is resolution to other issue. However, I have added the jars specified in that resolution.

Comment: try to set the content type as 'application/json'

Answer (score 1):

406 from service means the response type service is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.

```
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

check with above code.

Comment: Added this code but still not working. HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: Any luck, after adding the header.

Comment: No Luck.. I have changed the ResponseEntity<Boolean> to ResponseEntity<String> and it is working.

Comment: your have set the header type as "application/json" or "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following request header:

```
Accept: "*/*"
```