# Why am I getting 406 calling API that returns "long"

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, httprequest, spring-json

I am developing REST apis with Spring Boot and JPA. One of the endpoints consumes JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/controller/",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "text/plain")
    public long persistController(@RequestBody DoorController doorController) {
        return 10;  
    }
```

I simplified the logic in this api just for debugging purposes.

Entity class DoorController looks like this:
public class DoorController implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "DOOR_CTRLR_ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "MSG_ID")
private long messageID;

@Column(name = "CTRLR_SERL_NBR")
private String controllerSerialNumber;

@Column(name = "SAP_EQUIP_NBR")
private String sapEquipNumber;

@Column(name = "CTRLR_TYP")
private String controllerType;

@Column(name = "PREV_CTRLR_SERL_NBR")
private String prevControllerSerialNumber;
```

Then I started the app and tested the endpoint using Swagger-ui. The request body is the following JSON:

```
{
  "controllerSerialNumber": "x00001",
  "controllerType": "swing",
  "prevControllerSerialNumber": "",
  "sapEquipNumber": "",
}
```

I did some research, it seems for older Spring, you need to explicitly add `jackson` dependency. But for current Spring Boot, it is already included.

No error on the server side. When I debug it and placed a break point at `return 10;` in the controller class, after stepping over this statement, it would redirect to `sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl` in a Class File Editor and show `source not found`. What does this mean and why am I still getting 406?

**EDIT**:
After some debugging, I may have found the problem. Now if I change the return type from `long` to `string` or void, it will not give me 406. None of the numeric data types work. Tried `int`, `double`.

I already set `produces = "text/plain"`. Now the question becomes how to return `long` in rest API?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable

Comment: @AlfredoMunguia I debugged the code, it is reading JSON correctly. 406 happens at return. It has to do with return type `long`. Other types all work, e.g. `String`.