# Spring Boot:- [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently learning Spring Boot. I tried creating a method with PostMapping Annotation on it which will return a UserDetails object. I shared the code samples below. In the UserDetails Bean Class I have not created any setters or getters.  I have just created a parameterized constructor. When I hit the URL, I am getting a error in the console and also 406 status in the PostMan. When I add the getters and setters, I am getting the correct response. Kindly help me why there is no response when I don't add the getter and setter in the bean class.

UserDetails.java

```java
package com.example.VideoVerification.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;


public class UserDetails {
    String userid;
    String username;

    public UserDetails(String userid, String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    /*public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }*/
}
```

Controller class

```java
package com.example.VideoVerification.controller;

import com.example.VideoVerification.request.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;

@RestController
public class APIController
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/getUserDetails")
    public UserDetails getUserDetails()
    {
       return new UserDetails("1111","Tom");
    }
}
```

Response in PostMan without getter and setter in Bean class

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2022-06-03T16:46:14.562+00:00",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "path": "/getUserDetails"
}
```

Exception in Console

```
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

Response when I add getter and setter in Bean class

```json
{
    "userid": "1111",
    "username": "Tom"
}
```

Please help me to know why Spring Boot behaves in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Fields must be either `public` or have (public) getters to be serialized to JSON and (public) setters to be deserialized from JSON.

### Issue

Your fields have no access modifier, thus by default they are `package private`.
Without getters your fields are neither visible for classes outside the package.

```
public class UserDetails {
    String userid;  // package private
    String username;
}
```

By default Jackson can only access public fields directly or by (public) getters/setters.

#### Spring can't provide the accepted response format

Because the requesting client (your Postman) only seems to accept only media-type `application/json` (see [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) request-header) the content-negotiation fails because Jackson through [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) can't serialize the class.

Thus Spring fails to write the requested response format JSON out of returned object of type `UserDetails`.

As a consequence Spring throws a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` resulting in a response with HTTP status [**406 Not Acceptable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406).

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

#### Try something simple

Try `Accept: text/plain` as request-header in Postman. Spring should choose the [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) and try to call the method `toString()` of your class instance to get the accepted `text/plain` representation.

#### See also

- [Spring JSON request getting 406 (not Acceptable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)
- Java By Examples: [Serialize Package-Private Fields using Jackson](http://www.javabyexamples.com/jackson-can-serialize-package-private-fields/)
- Baeldung: [Jackson - Decide What Fields Get (De)Serialized](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not)
- Baeldung: [Http Message Converters with the Spring Framework](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest#2-responsebody)